# Get only the first link of a URLs list with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, url, beautifulsoup

I parsed an entire HTML file, extracting some URLs with Beautifulsoup module in Python, with this peace of code:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    for line in link :
        if "condition" in line :

           print link.get("href")
```

and i get in the shell a series of links that observe the condition in the if loop:

- http:// ..link1
- http:// ..link2
- .
- .
- http:// ..linkn

how can i put in a variable "output" only the first link of this list?

**EDIT:**

The web page is : http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=p970 , the script have to return the first short URL (http://get.cm/...) in the HTML page.

Comment: The link loop parse ALL the <a href> </a> strings in the HTML page, the line loop flows again the cicle checking condition in the if cicle, so it prints only the URLs that observe the condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a oneliner:

```
import re

soup.find('a', href=re.compile('^http://get.cm/get'))['href']
```

to assign it to a variable just:

```
variable=soup.find('a', href=re.compile('^http://get.cm/get'))['href']
```

I have no idea what exactly are you doing so i will post the full code from scratch:
NB! if you use bs4 change the imports

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

request = urllib2.Request("http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=p970")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
variable=soup.find('a', href=re.compile('^http://get.cm/get'))['href']
print variable

>>> 
http://get.cm/get/4jj
```

Comment: i tried closing the cicle with break and assign the link to a variable in the line loop but at this time the shell does not print anything.

Comment: yep, after the end of cicle using `break` with `print output`

Comment: i've fixed Indentation but shell returns nothing

Comment: Shell continues to return me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more easily and clearly in BeautifulSoup without loops.

Assuming your parsed BeautifulSoup object is named `soup`:

```
output = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='a' and "condition" in tag).attrs['href']
print output
```

Note that the `find` method returns only the first result, while `find_all` returns all of them.

Comment: This solution give me this error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'`

Comment: That's because you didn't implement the `lambda` correctly.  What I wrote for you was a sample using the obviously incorrect `"condition" in tag`.  You're getting the `AttributeError` because `soup.find` isn't finding any objects for which the `lambda` returns `True`, and so then you're attempting to call `attrs` on `None`.  I would have been able to provide a better answer had you given the website you were pulling originally.