# Getting the first URL out of a list of URL's using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull out the first URL in a list of URL tags using beautifulsoup and am getting hung up.  So far I have been able to get the results that I'm looking for using the following bit of code.

```
rows = results.findAll('p',{'class':'row'})
for row in rows:
  for link in row.findAll('a'):
    print(link)
```

This prints three `<a>` tags similar to the following.

```
<a href="http://something.foo">1</a>
<a href="http://something.bar">2</a>
<a href="http://something.foobar">3</a>
```

What I am looking to do is to extract out just the URL from the first a href.  [I found another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883352/get-only-the-first-link-of-a-urls-list-with-beautifulsoup) that describes doing this with some regex but so far I haven't been able to get that to work correctly.

I keep getting this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scraper.py", line 25, in <module>
    for link in row.find('a', href=re.compile('^http://')):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.  Let me know what other details I need to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `findAll` if you only want the first result - you can use `find`. 
Html attributes are exposed as a dictionary in BeautifulSoup. 
Finally, if the second argument to find is a string instead of a dict, it's used as the class. You could also provide it as a named argument: `find('p', class='row')`.

Knowing this, you can accomplish what you want with a simple line:

```
results.find('p','row').find('a')['href']
```

Comment: That seems to work but what I'm ultimitely trying to do is grab a bunch of URL's from some structured data.  So the solution works for one URL but how would I make that work in a larger set of data?  That is why I made a row variable and then iterate over it, is there a better way?