# how to get only the first get.("href")

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, dataframe

```
try: 
    link = music.find_all("a")
    #print link
    for link_music in link:
            music= link_music.get('href')
            print music
            musicData['Link'].append(music)
except:
    musicData['Link'].append("")

dr = pd.DataFrame(musicData)
dr
```

---

I am trying to get only the 'href' with 'http' in it.. but .get(href) also gets the '#'

[image: Output of Code#1]

---

```
try: 
    link = music.find_all("a")
    #print link
    for link_music in link:
            music= link_music.get('href')[2:]
            #print music
            musicData['Link'].append(music)
except:
    musicData['Link'].append("")

dr = pd.FataFrame(musicData)
dr
```

---

with [2:] , I get 'href' but for some reasome 'ht' from https:// gets removed and the table gets populated as in picture 2.

[image: Output of Code#2]

---

What can I do to make dataframe have only the 'http href'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only the first link of a URLs list with BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883352/get-only-the-first-link-of-a-urls-list-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @Maria:  Can you pass me sample input html file and respective output by email vivekbsable@gmail.com ?

Comment: @Maria: ok waiting for your email..